# How to change the Logo of the prebuilt themes chosen in Community Cloud?

Tags: customer-community, customer-portal, community-builder

Basically I want to change "Jepsen" to my company logo as below :

[image: Jepson theme]

I have tried going into Theme > Manage Branding Sets > Edit.

However when I choose "Edit", nothing happens.

[image: Theme edit settings]

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your logo in Theme > Images > Company logo in the community builder

[image: Theme branding lightning community]

[image: Theme branding lightning community]